# jQuery load external site page

Tags: jquery, load

Is it possible to load a single page from an external website?

I am trying to show up a single page but cannot seem to get it to work

```
$("#response").load("http://domain.com", function(response, status, xhr) {
   if (status == "error") {
      var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
      alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
   }
 });
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you'll need 1 line of PHP :)

Comment: Take a look here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh767443.aspx

Comment: If you only need RSS feeds and you don't mind relying on Google you could  use [jquery-feeds](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're running into a **cross domain policy** issue cause AJAX (for security reasons) will not let you grab content from a page that does not sit on the same domain.

**To get rid of it and accomplish your task:**
 you need a PHP file you can call `grabber.php` with just this line of PHP:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']); ?>
```

Than inside your html (or whatever file just do like:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="response"></div>

</body>

<script>
$(function(){
    var contentURI= 'http://domain.com #element';    // URL TO GRAB + # of any desired element // if needed :)
    $('#response').load('grabber.php?url='+ contentURI);
});
</script>

</html>
```

Why does this work?

- now, AJAX is sending a simple GET request to the `grabber.php` page,
- `grabber.php` echoes the desired content
- now the content is on your (server) domain!
- and AJAX is happy to serve you :)

Comment: this is great. One issue though. I notice many sites lose their absolute paths once pulling it. Do you know any tips to pull the page and keep it intact?

Comment: @andehlu You could add the loaded contents into an iframe, this should keep the paths in order.

Comment: @WessamElMahdy depents if you just want to admire the loaded page or you want to actually do some stuff with the loaded elements....

Comment: The comments speak to my problem, which is that the page content that loads is a frameset, and the frameset contents lose their absolute paths, resulting in "Page Not Found" or "Object Not Found" errors as the only content.

Comment: keep in mind that with this soution the second url's server sees the ip of your server not the client's ip.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to load a page on a different domain?

If yes, then it seems you got a cross-domain policy on your way...