# Unable to open a page in DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load a certain page load in fixed width div on click of a link, so far I made on clicking the link it does nothing, I given the code below can anyone help me solve it. I also Added the Fiddle.

HTML

```
<div id="top_Bar">
     <a href="#" id="ListLink">LIST LINK TEST</a> 
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

JS

```
 $("#ListLink").click(function() {
        $('#content')
           .load('google.com');
    });
```

CSS

```
#content{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Here is the fiddle for this code **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMHasnain/0q61you2/)**

Comment: If you don't work in Google, then you have problems: you are trying to load into the `<div>` page from another domain.

Comment: so what your saying is I can only load my own local site pages. external pages are not supported or if I am wrong correct me plz.

Comment: @Regent, I don't think that's the problem. From http://api.jquery.com/load/ : It is roughly equivalent to `$.get(url, data, success)` except that it is a method rather than global function and it has an implicit callback function. However browsers might restrict cross-domain Ajax requests like you rightly pointed out. It's not an issue with the `load` function.

Comment: @VivekPradhan ...and `$.get` is shortcut for `$.ajax`, which has restrictions for cross-domain requests.

Comment: @MHHasnain I can suggest to search in Google for _jquery ajax cross domain request_: JSONP data type, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header and other ways.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999573/jquery-load-external-site-page

Comment: @EthernalHour The link to the question you gave solution holds php solution I don't want php because I am not using it, I want to do it with html and JS or Jquery. but thanks for the information you gave.

Comment: In order to accomplish loading external site you need to use it, you cannot do it with jquery alone as it explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you cannot retriew the other domain:

Additional Notes:

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol.

see in http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Please include sample scenario or sample code.It's make more clear

Answer (score 1):

Try waiting until the document loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ListLink").click(function() {
        $('#content')
           .load('google.com');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be the cross-domain issue.
Open your web console(F12) and see whether you have got the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * " related error. or else follow the below test steps.

1. if you are using chrome browser, close or kill all the chrome instances.
2. open a command line (cmd) and go to your "chrome" installation folder.
3. issue this command to open the chrome in security disable mode: 
   chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
4. run your application on that chrome window and check whether you got the www.google.com inside your div.

if that is working, that confirms you have the cross-domain issue.
to sort that one, you have couple of techniques out there.
1. using cross-domain.xml inside your app server.
2. use jsonp callback function with your $.ajax()
3. configure cors.jar in your path

search how to use above techniques to sort out your cross-domain issue.
This is just a guidance for you..hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for giving me your thoughts on this post. I found the answer to this.

I just create another page in my local site folder and call it. I admit I was wasting time on loading external site.

once again I thanks all for your answers.