# How to get css background image url from external website

Tags: jquery, html, css

On a internal page you can get the background image easily with jQuery. For example:

```
var url = $('.headerImg').css('background-image');
```

But how to get the url from an external website ?
For a better understanding what is meant here - of course this is not possible:

```
var url = $('www.website.de:/.headerImg').css('background-image');
```

Is there any way?

Comment: You can try to create an iframe and put the external site in it. Then you can enter in the iframe and get the css

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```js
$("body").css("background-image", "url('https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTALmLDCnfMHOLz6NTj8Sxy5X6A--LYF7j0lT9Uoq7bU6LdImY')");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery AJAX

```
$.get( "your-url", function( data ) {
  // display the loaded HTML: $( ".result" ).html( data );
  //data is the loaded html page. You can select the element you want from here
  // like $('.headerImg').css('background-image');
});
```

For more documentation see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: I guess it's not allowed to load content with ajax from external website.

Comment: So.. You want the bg image from another website HTML without knowing the url.. Than you have to load the full website inside your project with an iframe i think.

Comment: @ChristianMichael see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999573/jquery-load-external-site-page maybe this will help?