# How to extract a part of a page from external webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get an element with a div id from an external web page.

This is the code I tried to work with but it doesn't return anything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Arial;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <b>Output:</b>
  <ol id="tablepress-34_wrapper"></ol>

  <script>
    $( "#tablepress-34_wrapper" ).load( "https://mrafiee.net/daily-bonus-digital-communication/" );
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

For example, I want to get the table showing in that page in another external page. How can I do it ?
Thanks

Comment: use a proper scraping library to do this

Comment: It doesn't return anything because of cross-domain restrictions. You'll have to use a different method to grab data from an external domain. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999573/jquery-load-external-site-page

Comment: [Use BeautifulSoup4 library](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I've used it previously and it plays quite well

Comment: *"it doesn't return anything"* - are you sure it doesn't return an error?  You're not checking for one

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing is due to the [CORS policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). A workaround would be to use a proxy service such as https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/; For instance the following injects the first `div` of the remote site into the `body`

```
$('body').load('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://mrafiee.net/daily-bonus-digital-communication/ div')
```